# PnP Modern Search + Microsoft Graph Toolkit registry issue

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I've created an extension library for PnP Modern Search Results so I can render a specific layout for my search results, which just consist of news pages.
In essence the layout is just a grid of 4 items, with an image as a background and different text on top.
I would like to use the MGT Person component to display the author's name and avatar.
I'm importing the required components into my main component file

`import { Person, ViewType } from '@microsoft/mgt-react';`

And returning the component in jsx, passing in the CreatedBy value

```
<div className="newsSubTitle">
   <Person personQuery={CreatedBy} view={ViewType.oneline}></Person>
</div>
```

Everything compiles fine, I can make a package and incorporate it into my sharepoint site. But when I add the webpart and configure it. I just get a host of errors saying that all the mgt components have already been registered.
The person component is in the html, but without any data inside.
I am assuming these errors are the reason nothing is being displayed.

[image: example of modern search layout with errors]

I have tried following this thread but get different errors if I change the imports, essentially preventing the webpart from working at all. I'm using mgt-react v3.1.3, so I'm unsure if this fix is still relevant.
[link to mgt bug](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/229)

These are the errors I get when I change the imports (following the bug thread above), which basically just tell me the library is broken
[image: error when imports changed]

I have also tried to add disambiguation, which happily names the mgt-person component differently but I still get all the errors.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of the PnP modern search web parts are you using? 

You mentioned trying disambiguation, did you also ensure that followed the guidance on using lazy / dynamic imports?

If you have a repro please file an issue on the mgt repo: https://aka.ms/mgt/issues

Comment: I was using the latest version (4.10.1) and from a discussion I raised on their github, I was able to work around the issue by emitting the person component as html markup instead. https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/discussions/3447

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: As mentioned before, I’ve only managed a workaround. On plenty of other occasions I’ve had issues with modern search and other web parts, if they are both using the mgt components. An example being the personal calendar from the sp-starter-kit. If modern search has MS Graph enabled, then the calendar web part breaks

Comment: Ok, there's a lot of layers of things going on here. If you have mgt-spfx installed as it appears you do then when a component using that is in the page that solution is loaded and will register the custom element.
As soon as mgt-react based dependencies are imported then custom element registration occurs, as imports are hoisted then unless you use a dynamic import or lazy load then the registration happens ahead of disambiguation being applied and will break a lot of your code.
To use multiple instance of mgt in a page can be done, but troubleshooting it needs full reproductions.